# Predicate Logic Equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

It is from discrete mathematics notes. 
These are part of the biconditional tautologies.

E29. (∀x)A(x) →B ⇔ (∃x)(A(x)→B)

E30. (∃x)A(x) →B ⇔ (∀x)(A(x)→B)

I don't understand how these formulas are said to be equivalent. 
What is the difference in interpretation between (∀x)A(x) →B and (∀x)(A(x)→B) ? 
How should I interpret those formulas? and how can I prove it?
Thank you!

Comment: Reagrding you question about the difference in interpretation, you might want to take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146114/logical-equivalence-of-quantified-propositions-involving-if-then

Comment: Consider a simple example in the language of arithmetic : $\forall x (x=0) \to (1=0)$ is TRUE while $\forall x [(x=0) \to (1=0)]$ is FALSE.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051407/is-it-possible-to-convert-forall-quantifiers-to-exists-quantifiers-without/3051463#3051463